# Packaging up the .net framework with a .net application deployment

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment

Can you package up the .Net framework in an installer created in Visual Studio? If so how?

I've seen this done with Install4J packaging a JVM but I think that was the JVM to run Install4J.

Comment: This article should help: [HOW TO: Distribute the .NET Framework with a Visual Studio .NET Deployment Project (MSDN)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733)

Answer (score 1):

I just learned this lesson about deployment projects: the .MSI file delivers the application to the target machine, but that SETUP.EXE is the bootstrapper that installs prerequisites, such as the .NET Framework, MDAC, or Windows Installer. I specified the .NET Framework as a prerequisite but, because I only distributed the .MSI, no checks were run and the app crashed when starting up without the framework.

To ensure your prerequisites are on the target machine, you need to distribute the setup.exe too.

Answer (score 0):

Sucky, yeah - I created an installer just recently before realizing that the .Net Framework (which was one of the things I needed to install) was required.  I ended up making a c++ program that installed .Net before my installer was launched.

Seems kind of odd to me to offer the ability to create an installer and not have it offer to install what it needs to run.  Kinda pointless at that point, eh?  Unless you know that every machine you give the installer to will have the necessary components...

Oh well, live and learn