# Packaging a .NET Application So It Will Run On A Computer Without .NET

Tags: c#, .net, redistributable

I have been recently trying to deploy a C# application on a computer that does not have .NET installed.

I know that there have been *many* questions around the same topic here on StackOverflow. Here are a few of them, of which I read the responses to all:

[Packaging up the .net framework with a .net application deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162845/packaging-up-the-net-framework-with-a-net-application-deployment)

[Run a .net application without installing .net client profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289213/run-a-net-application-without-installing-net-client-profile)

[Run C# windows application in windows XP without installing .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930831/run-c-sharp-windows-application-in-windows-xp-without-installing-net-framework)

So all of the responses to the above questions state that it is impossible without specific software, etc. One software mentioned was the [Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/navigator.html?demo). The only problem with that is that I cannot seem to be able to run the application after it has been processed by Salamender. I understand that this in itself is impossible, as it requires the .NET virtual machine to run. However, in the past, I have made Java applications and along with them, I shipped the entire JVM. Surprisingly, they still worked. So the reason why this is not a duplicate of the above questions is because my true question is:

What items of the .NET framework would I need to package? If I do manage to package all, would placing them in the same directory as the application I'm running allow the application to run?

I found one solution to this, the [Microsoft .NET Redist Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=26). The only problem with this is that it has a GUI of its own. Aside from that, it would be a perfect fit. So, could anyone tell me one of two things:

Is there a command-line .NET package, and if so, where do I download it?

If there isn't, or it would be impractical to do so, approximately what directories would I need to copy from the .NET installations?

I understand that these files and directories are system specific, and that my .NET installation may not work on your computer, but if C# is like Java, then this should be achievable. Is it? Size is not a limitation, it does not matter to me whether or not the application and all its files is 1GB, or if it is only 1MB.

If in case there is no other solution, I used [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check all the dependencies of my program. If I were to package most of them, would my application, in theory, work?

Comment: These static linkers are a terrible idea.  Your application will not benefit from security fixes and other enhancements (ala Windows Update).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For .NET, you really *must* just install the appropriate .NET framework.  The .NET framework installation does include command line options to allow for silent installs, such as:

```
dotnetfx35.exe /q /norestart
```

For details on the command line options, see the [options for 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx) and for [.NET 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/12/10011664.aspx).

That being said, most installation packages will handle these details for you as part of the installation.  Using a decent installer will take care of this dependency automatically.

Comment: Is there any command to make it show how much it has installed, in a format like a percentage, or current file extracting... etc.? I checked the options for 3.5 link you posted, but did not find anything among those lines in there.

Comment: First you don't want a GUI and now you do?

Comment: I do not want a GUI. And the files extracting is not a must, but I was wondering if there was a command-line style percentage or extractor, something like, say wget. I'm not sure if that counts as a GUI. If it does, sorry I raised confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the pieces of the .NET Framework you need, you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). It supports shipping the runtime without installing just like you would a JVM, or you can statically link against the binaries to create a native executable .

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to deploy your application (and presuming the setup process doesn't need to be too complex), you can simply create a [Setup project in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx) and then bootstrap the prerequisites (.NET framework, and other stuff you think you might need).

You can follow the steps described in these MSDN articles:

- [How to create a Setup project in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx)
- [How to add prerequisites to a Setup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx)

A walkthrough is given in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi).

For more complex deployment scenarios (such as installing device drivers along your app, or better localization support), I would recommend looking into [WiX (Windows Installer XML) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It's a toolset that builds Windows installation packages, which you configure using XML files inside Visual Studio. WiX also supports various [bootstrapping scenarios](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm).

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500(v=vs.100).aspx) covers the differences between VS Setup projects, WiX, and InstallShield.