# How convert A ".Net" assembly (C# Language) to "non .Net" assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, converters, windows

I want to run my `Windows Form Application` (Created Using With VS 2012 - Targeting .NET 3.5 - written in C#) on PCs that don't have .NET 3.5 installed on them.
There are many PCs out there for me to consider, and I can not do that.
So should I change my framework and I not rewrite that big project again?
Is there a way to convert the output exe file to another language that does not need .NET Framework?

Comment: You can rewrite it without relying on .NET, or you can pay someone to rewrite it without using .NET .. that being said, you likely just want the executable (or setup) to automatically help the user install the required .NET framework.

Comment: Why not just provide the required framework? You could distribute it with your application - See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050160/packaging-a-net-application-so-it-will-run-on-a-computer-without-net

Comment: One big problem is it's not just your code that you'd need to convert. It's all the code from .Net that your application uses. It would be far simpler to install .Net. You could also try targeting .Net2.0. There can't be many Windows machines out there without .Net2.0

Comment: in windows 8 .net 2.0 was disabled | i don't know why do they do this crap?

Comment: the upgrade to 3.5 from 2.0 is cumulative; Make sure people understand there is no harm in installing 3.5 if the system already has the 2.0

Comment: You can embed .NET in your installer so it's a non-issue.

Comment: So many misconceptions, so little time.

Comment: Have you verified the size of your expected userbase running an OS incapable of running .NET 3.5?

Comment: http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you clarify?

Comment: @LuisFilipe: Where do I start?  Read the premises in the question again, and the question that results from those premises.  Read the comments in the answer below about compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools that will package everything up into a single binary for you such as .net reactor http://www.eziriz.com/

Comment: did you see this "Our products are compatible with all .NET languages and supports all Operating Systems where .NET Framework or Mono can be installed." on http://www.eziriz.com/ -> i think we still need .net after protection!

Comment: i dont think so - it will package everything up for you

Comment: what about http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/? do we need .net after packing?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compile C# .NET into native code. The only solution I see is to set the Project's Target Framework to .NET 2.0 which would allow you to XP and up no matter what.

Comment: This is not strictly speaking true actually. You CAN compile to native code. It's just so clumsy that no one ever does it.

Comment: @sircodesalot: That's pretty opinionated, and largely wrong.  The more truthful answer is that you can compile it to native code using NGEN, but it still requires the .NET Framework.

Comment: ... right, you CAN, but it's clumsy (because it still requires .NET), and thus no one does it.

Comment: Clumsy is as clumsy does.  Saying that something is clumsy imparts no useful information.

Comment: besides what about windows 8? in win 8 we don't have .net 2.0 - should install from windows features?

Comment: @sircodesalot well if JIT Compiler is used I guess you could use ngen.exe to turn the IL into native. But that's not compiling, that's refactoring. Using JIT Compiler alone, you cannot compile into native code. Using another compiler, sure you can.

Comment: More misconceptions.  Where do I find the time to refute them all?

Comment: @MoonLight derp... I forgot Windows 8 doesn't include .NET 2.0-3.5. That's annoying...

Comment: Those applications should still run just fine on .NET 4.0.  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee941656(v=vs.100).aspx) for possible exceptions, but they are few.